# Zend Framework User Registration- adding to db

Tags: php, zend-framework

Hey, so I'm coding a php application, and I've run into an error, which I am for some reason not seeing (me being really bad at coding and lack of sleep may have something to do with it.

Anyway, here's my tricky problem :)

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected $end, expecting T_FUNCTION

and the code:

The model

```
class Model_DbTable_Users extends Zend_Db_Table_Abstract
{
    protected $_name = 'users';

    public function addUser($username, $password, $email)
    {
        $data = array( 'username' => $username,
                       'password'    => $password,
                       'email'    => $email);
        $this->insert($data);
    }
```

and the action

```
public function stage1Action()
{
    $form = new Form_RegisterForm;
    $this->view->form = $form;

    $request = $this->getRequest();
    #if the form is submitted
    if($request->isPost()){
        #validated automatically by the form-errors echoed if invalid
        if($form->isValid($this->_request->getPost())) {
            $username = $form->getValue('username');
            $password = $form->getValue('password');
            $email = $form->getValue('email');

            $users = new Model_DbTable_Users;
            $users->addUser($username, $password, $email);

            $this->_helper->redirector('stage2');
        }
    }
}
```

I get this action after pressing the submit button.

Any help greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance

Comment: In this example, your model is not closed by }. Please specify the full error msg, including the file name.

Comment: haha, yes, that is it- jeeze, I will go and get some sleep now. Time to go when you don't see stuff like that. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: The clue was actually in the error message (really): unexpected end. The end of the file was not expected because the closing brace was absent

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you aren't putting `()` on the end of your class names when you instantiate a class. Change this:

```
$form = new Form_RegisterForm;
```

to this

```
$form = new Form_RegisterForm();
```

Do the same thing for `Model_DbTable_Users`.

Hope this helps!

Comment: am I meant to? I thought that was just for functions. . . I'm very new to this you see

Comment: Yes. When you create a new instance of a class, you put parentheses at the end. This lets you use a constructor. I.e.: $me = new person("mattbasta");

Having empty parentheses tells the interpreter that you're only looking to use the default constructor.